# Express only serving css file in main page

Tags: node.js, express

I am learning node and using expressjs the problem is that the css file is only working on the main page and not any other page following is the code for the app:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

// assets
 app.use(express.static("public"));

// simple file testing
app.get("/anything/:stuff", function(req, res){
var stuff = req.params.stuff;
res.render("love.ejs", {stuff: stuff});
});

// posts page
var books = [
{title:"Harry Potter",author:"JK Rowling",editions:7},
{title:"Peere Kamil",author:"Humaira Saeed",editions:4},
{title:"Mushaf",author:"Abdullah khan",editions:2}
];

app.get("/books", function(req, res){
res.render("books.ejs",{books:books});
});

app.listen(3000, process.env.IP, function(){
console.log("Serving Now!");
});
```

The following is the code for the page where it is not working.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" />
<title>demo app</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>You fell in love with : <%= stuff %> </h1>

<%
if(stuff.toUpperCase() === "WAQAS"){ %>
    <P>GOOD CHOICE HE IS THE BEST</p>
<% } %>



<p>P.S This is the love.ejs file</p>
</body>
</html>
```

The file is under public directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an absolute URL for the CSS file, so the browser doesn't look for it relative to the current URL:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/app.css" />
```

Explanation: say that you open the URL `/anything/helloworld` in your browser. When your HTML contains just `app.css`, without the leading slash in front of it, the browser will try and load `/anything/app.css` (because without that slash it's relative to the current URL), which doesn't point to your CSS file.

When you add the leading slash, `express.static` will be able to find the CSS file in `public/`.

Comment: @WaqasShahbaz I added an explanation.